# strange json foreach get specified value

Tags: php, json, foreach

i have a json code,tried a lot of ways but still can't get the data from the json

json:

```
echo $answer->option; 
// will output    

{"customer_ans":["qqq","sss"],
    "show_image":["images/a.png","images/b.png"]},
    {"customer_ans":["ooo","ooo","ooo"],
    "show_image":["images/a.png","images/b.png","images/c.png"]}
    ...thesame...blablabla
```

when i tried

```
foreach($answer->option as $mydata)

    {

         foreach($mydata->customer_ans as $values)
         {
              echo $values . "\n";
         }
    }
```

no output and I tried

```
$ansopts = json_decode( $answer->option,true );
for($i=0;$i<count($ansopts["customer_ans"]);$i++) {
    echo $ansopts["customer_ans"][$i];
}
```

still no output!

So how can I get the customer_ans value?

**********************************************Update*****************

```
for($i=0;$i<count($ansopts);$i++) {
    echo var_export( $ansopts["customer_ans"][$i]);
}
```

no ouput

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_decode($answer->option, true), true).'</pre>';
```

no output

var_dump function:

```
var_dump($answer->option);
// will output
string(291) "{"customer_ans":["aaa","bbb"],"show_image":["images/a.png","images/a.png"]},{"customer_ans":["ccc","ddd","eee"],"show_image":["images/a.png","images/b.png","images/c.png"]}"
```

Many thanks everyone!

Comment: Your first code block makes no sense. Fix it so it's legible and show the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_decode($answer->option, true), true).'</pre>';`

Comment: thanks for reply,but the json code is come from the program,so if want change this,will take really long time.

Comment: So `echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_decode($answer->option, true), true).'</pre>';` doesn't format it nicely?

Comment: Change `echo $ansopts["customer_ans"][$i];` to `var_export( $ansopts["customer_ans"][$i]);` in the second code block. I thing you have to do `$ansopts[$i]["customer_ans"][0];` to get `qqq` and with `[1]` to get `sss`

Comment: And  change `count($ansopts["customer_ans"])` to `count($ansopts)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
#the json is a littel invalid to parse, missing [ ] around it 
$ansopts = json_decode('['.trim((string)$answer->option).']',true );

//test for errors
print json_last_error_msg ();
//to see it for real
var_export($ansopts);

//loop 
for($i=0;$i<count($ansopts);$i++) {
    echo $ansopts[$i]["customer_ans"][0];#qqq
    echo $ansopts[$i]["customer_ans"][1];#sss
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir,var_export($ansopts); will output Null,and for function no output.

Comment: Dont get it, you say `echo $answer->option; // will output` and var_dump(); shows nothing? Then the json string is not vaild at all. Try `json_decode( trim((string)$answer->option),true );`

Comment: Many thanks JustOnUnderMillions!it's what i want,just test it looks everything works fine!

Comment: Dear JustOnUnderMillions,could you change it in foreach?thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$ansopts = json_decode( $answer->option,true );
foreach($ansopts as $mydata)
{
     foreach($mydata->customer_ans as $values)
     {
          echo $values . "\n";
     }
}
```

or you can try to dump the variable first

```
print_r($ansopts);exit;
```

Comment: Hi Sir, print_r($ansopts); no output