# sql get specified value

Tags: mysql, sql, json

after the question "[strange json foreach get specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041324/strange-json-foreach-get-specified-value)" has solve,i think change the program is a better solution,
same data here

```
{"customer_ans":["qqq","sss"],
    "show_image":["images/a.png","images/b.png"]},
    {"customer_ans":["ooo","ooo","ooo"],
    "show_image":["images/a.png","images/b.png","images/c.png"]}
    ...thesame...blablabla
```

in database,if i want select all customer_ans in sql use Select and Where,how can i do?

```
SQL
--------------------------------
Select 
Where
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a comment to another question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strange json foreach get specified value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041324/strange-json-foreach-get-specified-value)

Comment: @Ollie it's not totally the same with my another question,this question is i want get the data use sql function,not php

Answer (score 0):

after change the source program,and it auto change the json output,so this question closed!